# iOS In-app purchase multiple subscription groups

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

I'm trying to figure out how to proceed with multiple subscription groups with iOS in-app purchase.

Suppose I have multiple content providers users can subscribe to, and for each there are different tiers of subscriptions as follows:

```
Provider 1 : Basic, Plus, Premium

Provider 2 : Basic, Plus, Premium

...

Provider n : Basic, Plus, Premium.
```

My understanding is we do this by creating subscription group and within each subscription groups create Basic, Plus, Premium. Users can upgrade/downgrade plan within the group.

My issue is we add/remove content providers all the time, therefore its not scaleable to keep adding new subscription groups every time we have new provider.

Comment: That's what you will need to do.  Alternatively you can use non-autorenewing subscriptions and manage the various tiers and providers on your back-end with a single set of IAPs

Comment: @Paulw11 , that sucks, we want to do auto-renewable.

Comment: Im also looking for a solution for this kind of problem. Multiple subscription while the items is dynammic (user generated).